# Telegram bot c# publish the code

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I'm editing the question since the comment below gave me a good source code and I solved the first part.

Anyone looking for a good example on how to program a Telegram bot, check [here](http://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot.examples)

My main problem is: I've written the code, I've created a bot. Now I don't really know how to link the bot and the code, I need to know the two following points:

- How can I debug a bot?
- How can I publish the code way to make the published bot use it?

Thanks all

Comment: if not already do check out the samples here https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot.examples

Comment: Thanks for the link! I checked it and it was really useful. I just have the last problem unsolver.. how can I publish my code? I can't really fiure out how to make my bot interfacing with the C# code I've written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. Generally, a bot is just a ordinary application. You can use a API for the bot or you can develop the API calls yourself. It looks like you are quite unexperienced, so i suggest you to use a ready-to-go API for C#.

The bot you created has an ID, when you create you bot in whatever API you use, you have to specify this Key, it will link the application with the bot, everyone with this key can reply in your name, so keep it secret.

There are two methods of getting updates for your bot. You can use a webhook or long-polling. When using a pre-defined-API, you are probably using long-polling because it does not depend on the machine the bot is running on. In this case you can debug you bot without any problems, it is just a default application.

Comment: uhm I don't get a thing: I just need to put this code in my API and it automatically link to the bot wherever this webservice is running?

Comment: You dont need a webservice, the bot can run on it's own, it just needs an internet connection

Comment: But my bot has his custom methods and his custom functions. for example, writing "/current" you get your current status on the application (for example, dunno, hour spent on it). This is what I need to achieve

Comment: Yes, but all the code for the bot runs on the server, not on the phone so it is not important where your bot's application is running. It can reply the messages by the user from your personal computer or from a server, it does not matter.

Comment: So I just need to run the code with the token in my api on my server and I'm done, right?